# A bound on the eigenvalues of a product

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, spectral-radius

Let $A,B\in \mathbb{S}^n$ be such that $A\succ0,B\succ0$.

(a) Show that all eigenvalues of $BA$ are real and positive

(b) Let $B^{-1}=diag\{||{a_1}^T||_1,...,||{a_n}^T||_1\}$, where ${a_i}^T$ , $i=1,...,n$, are the rows of $A$.Prove that $$0<\lambda_i(BA)\le1 \ \  \forall i=1,...,n,$$
(c) Prove that $$\rho(I-\alpha BA)<1, \ \forall \alpha\in (0,2).$$

Comment: did you try to think about this at all?

Comment: Yes,indeed. I solved the first part easily but failed to solve the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good title, for $(a)$, we have that the spectre $\{\sigma\} $  of $XY$ is the same as $XY$ for all square matrices. So $\{\sigma(AB)\}=\{\sigma (B^{\frac{1}{2}}AB^{\frac{1}{2}})\}$ and that is $\in \mathbb{R}^+$.
For $(b)$ resp $(c)$ it is  sufficient to prove that $\lambda_{m}(BA)\le 1$ resp $|\lambda_m(I-\alpha BA)|\le  1$ ($\lambda_m$ is the maximal eigenvalue). It is well known using your notations  that $|\lambda_m( A)|\le \text{max}_i \|a_i^T\|_1$. Applying that to $BA$ of row $R_i$, $ \|R_i\|_1\le 1$

Comment: Can you please share any source related to that well-known fact or  prove it yourself?

Comment: Have you see Gresgorin circles...

Comment: I just checked the proof of Gershgorin circle theorem.Now I have a few questions to ask. First, for the right part of the b) part do we use the fact that A is actually positive definite.Second, why ∥Ri∥1≤1 but not ∥Ri∥1=1 and lastly, what about c) part.Thank you in advance!

Comment: Left part is from $(a)$, right part from the Greshgorin bound and $\|R_i\|\le 1$ you should know the form of $R_i$ the row of $BA$

Comment: yes it is $1$, you should try $c$, just guess the eigenvalues of $I-\alpha BA$.